# How to set focus on ComboBox in Windows Forms App (Visual Studio,VB.Net)?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, focus

**Update:** I was able to get the ComboBox to focus but I had to go into Project>Properties and switch the application type to "ConsoleApp" and then I was able to get the combobox to focus in blue. I would still love to know how to do this natively in Windows Forms app though, as .Focus() doesn't seem to work and everything else I tried:
[image]

**Original Question:** this is maybe a trivial question but I've searched on google and tried different methods but could not get my simple GUI Windows Form App (.NET) to set **focus** on one of my ComboBoxes after erroring (i.e. when ComboBox value is not selected, program should throw MessageBox error then set **focus** to that specific ComboBox). I've been trying .select() and focus() and changing the tab-index.

My two ComboBoxes are to the right of the From: and To: TextBoxes and have the names **cboFrom** and **cboTo**. The ComboBox style is **DropDownList**

Option Explicit: **ON**

Option Strict: **ON**

Option Infer: **Off**

And **unselected** Microsoft.VisualBasic for under "References" in project properties.

This is the GUI:
[image]

And how it looks when it throws error for a ComboBox is empty and Convert is clicked:
[image]

And this is the code that throws an Error message if any or both of the ComboBoxes are empty. It should **focus** back to the ComboBox that was empty, but it's not.

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click

    Dim dValueOfTxtBoxFrom As Double = 0

    If Me.cboFrom.SelectedIndex = -1 AndAlso Me.cboTo.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
      MessageBox.Show("Please select temperature units to convert from and to.", "Error: 10001", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
      'btnReset.Select() 'works fine

    ElseIf cboFrom.SelectedIndex = -1 OrElse cboTo.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
      MessageBox.Show("Please select temperature units to convert from and to.", "Error: 10001", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
      'btnExit.Select() 'works fine

    End If
```

Comment: Welp, when I changed the "Project properties" from Windows Form Application to Console Application, using cbo.To.Select() made the ComboBox blue when it error'd. The question is why doesn't this happen when in windows form application mode?

Comment: You add Me.cboFrom.focus() or Me.cboTo.Focus() dependig if one of them has the index  -1.

Comment: yeah,  I tried the Me.cboTo.focus() just to test it and it didn't work. The only thing I could get to work is to go into the Project properties and change it to "Console application" instead of Windows Form Application. And I used .select() method instead. It would show up blue like this when I ran the program https://i.imgur.com/wGBf2AX.png

I would love to learn how to get it to work naively on windows form apps though without having to switch it to a console app. The combobox boxes are DropDownList (read only) style and binding is Strict and Infer Off so I'm not sure if that matters

Comment: "And unselected Microsoft.VisualBasic for under "References" in project properties." <- why are you doing this? Is there a lot in this project? I'd suggest starting a new winforms and copy over your gui elements and code. What you're trying to achieve is absolutely normal and works.

Comment: I use this very often in my forms, so that the user can change the incorrect entry Selection. I concur with Andrew start a new Project and try it again.